# start reading incoming data from a serial port, using pyserial, when a specific character appears

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm trying to read incoming data from a weight scale (Lexus Matrix One). I want the code to start reading the 8 characters after `=` appears.

The problem is that sometimes the code does that, and other times it starts reading the data at the middle of the measurement sent by the scale, making it impossible to read properly. I'm using the `pyserial` module on python 3 on windows.

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial("COM4", baudrate=9600)
a=0
while a<10:
  b=ser.read(8)
  a=a+1
  print(b)
```

the expected result is: `b'= 0004.0'`

but sometimes I get: `b'4.0= 000'`

Comment: Where do you check for the '='?

Comment: I dont check for the "=" when I get the right result is because got lucky and started reading at the "=", i was wondering if there is a way to check, or to read it correctly

Answer (score 3):

I think we would need a little more information on the format of data coming from your weight scale to provide a complete answer.  But your current code only reads the first 80 bytes from the stream, 8 bytes at a time.

If you want to read the next 8 bytes following *any* equals sign, you could try something like this:

```py
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("COM4", baudrate=9600)
readings = []
done = False
while not done:
    current_char = ser.read()
    # check for equals sign
    if current_char == b'=':
        reading = ser.read(8)
        readings.append(reading)

    # this part will depend on your specific needs.
    # in this example, we stop after 10 readings
    # check for stopping condition and set done = True
    if len(readings) >= 10:
        done = True
```

Comment: thank you, it works, I dont know how to get more information on the format, I want to learn more on this protocol, where can I find literatire or something to really understand it

Comment: In many cases, sensors will come with some documentation that describes the format of data they pass over a serial port.  Sometimes it can take some time to understand, so a quicker way to start is to just print everything that comes through the serial port and look at what you get :)

Comment: If you're looking to learn more about the `serial` library, then you can check out the docs here: https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/ 

And if you're wanting to learn more about serial buses in general, SparkFun has a good intro: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/serial-communication/all